# Find the missing coordinates such that the three vectors form an orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

[image]

I'm at a complete loss as to how to solve this and I don't even know where to begin. Am I supposed to take the dot product and go from there?

Comment: First square can be instantly filled in since vectors have to be normal. Two middle squares can be filled in in the same way. Then last one is easy to fill in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

A normal vector $\vec u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)^T$ has norm $|\vec u|=\sqrt{u_1^2+u_2^2+u_3^2}=1$

So:

1) for the first vector $\vec u_1=(-0.8,-0.6,z_1)^T$  find $z_1$ such that $|\vec u_1|=1$ :

> $z_1=0$

2)  do the same for the second vector $\vec u_2=(x_2,y_2,-1)^T$ and find $x_2$ and $y_2$ :

> $x_2=y_2=0$

3) now find the third vector $\vec u_3=(x_3,0.8,z_3)^T$  such that it is orthogonal to the first and the second (this means that the dot products are null):

> $\vec u_1 \cdot \vec u_3=-0.8x_3+(-0.6)\cdot(0.8)+0 \cdot z_3=0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad x_3=-0.6$

and

> $\vec u_2\cdot \vec u_3=-1 \cdot z_3=0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad z_3=0$

and verify that $|\vec u_3|=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Orthonormal means two conditions have to be satisfied:

> (1) Each vector has norm/length 1
>
> (2) Each vector is orthogonal to the others (their dot product is
>   zero)

This is a sort of puzzle where you have to keep using those two facts to fill in squares one at a time. Using (1), you can immediately determine the other coordinates of the first and second vectors given. Now use (2) to figure out the missing coordinates of the last vector.